# Android: share and access a text file over LAN

Tags: java, android, lan

I am developing an Android application for the guest-relation team for a society. The main idea for the theme is that a single text file will be shared across a LAN. All members of team will have an android device and check the guests who have arrived. I have completed the system, now I want you guys to suggest me:

(I have not studied computer networks subject or anything related, so I hope a detailed answer about technology also)

1. How to share a text file over LAN?
2. How to access that file?
3. How to modify and save it?
4. Please mention all the tools that I will require.

Thanks.

Comment: So take a look into the `Socket` and `ServerSocket` classes that is a good way of sharing a txt file over LAN. You might just want to send over the updated information and not the whole file each and every time. Have all the Android devices (Throught the app) connected to the Server which will receive the new data (Save it or w.e. you want to do with it) then send back to all the other devices connected. The server will need to either be a computer or V.P.S. of some sort since `Socket` and `ServerSocket` are also W.A.N. so as long as your connected though the internet it should work over LAN